# How to release an object in a forin loop?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, memory-management

I'm new to cocoa / objective-c and i'm struggeling with the releases of my objects. I have the following code:

```
gastroCategoryList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *gastrocategory in gastrocategories) {
    NSString *oid = [gastrocategory objectForKey:@"id"];
    GastroCategory *gc = [[GastroCategory alloc] initWithId:[oid intValue] name:[gastrocategory objectForKey:@"name"]];
    [gastroCategoryList addObject:gc];
}
```

The analyzer shows me that the "gastrocategory" defined in the for is a potential memory leak. But i'm not sure if i can release this at the end of the for loop?

Also at the following code:

```
- (NSArray *)eventsForStage:(int)stageId {

    NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (Event *e in eventList) {
        if ([e stageId] == stageId) {
            [result addObject:e];
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

The Analyzer tells me that my "result" is a potential leak. But where should I release this?

Is there also a simple rule to memorize when i should use assign, copy, retain etc. at the @property ?

Another problem:

```
- (IBAction)showHungryView:(id)sender {
    GastroCategoriesView *gastroCategoriesView = [[GastroCategoriesView alloc] initWithNibName:@"GastroCategoriesView" bundle:nil];

    [gastroCategoriesView setDataManager:dataManager];

    UIView *currentView = [self view];
    UIView *window = [currentView superview];

    UIView *gastroView = [gastroCategoriesView view];

    [window addSubview:gastroView];

    CGRect pageFrame = currentView.frame;
    CGFloat pageWidth = pageFrame.size.width;
    gastroView.frame = CGRectOffset(pageFrame,pageWidth,0);

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    currentView.frame = CGRectOffset(pageFrame,-pageWidth,0);
    gastroView.frame = pageFrame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    //[gastroCategoriesView release];
}
```

I don't get it, the "gastroCategoriesView" is a potential leak. I tried to release it at the end or with autorelease but neither works fine. Everytime I call the method my app is terminating. Thank you very much again!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your loop, release each `gc` after adding it to the list since you won't need it in your loop scope anymore:

```
gastroCategoryList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *gastrocategory in gastrocategories) {
    NSString *oid = [gastrocategory objectForKey:@"id"];
    GastroCategory *gc = [[GastroCategory alloc] initWithId:[oid intValue] name:[gastrocategory objectForKey:@"name"]];
    [gastroCategoryList addObject:gc];
    [gc release];
}
```

In your method, declare `result` to be autoreleased to absolve ownership of it from your method:

```
NSMutableArray *result = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

// An alternative to the above, produces an empty autoreleased array
NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
```

**EDIT:** in your third issue, you can't release your view controller because its view is being used by the window. Setting it to autorelease also causes the same fate, only delayed.

You'll have to retain your `GastroCategoriesView` controller somewhere, e.g. in an instance variable of your app delegate.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you also know a rule for the @property problem?

Comment: @n3on: If a property is declared `retain` or `copy`, you should release its ivar in your class's `dealloc` method.

Comment: @BoltClock: ok thanks. But when should i use copy, retain or assign?

Comment: @n3on: Sherm Pendley's answer might help.

Comment: @BoltClock: have another problem, would be great if you could help me out. I edited my first posting.

Comment: @n3on: See if retaining it in your class helps.

Answer (score 3):

BoltClock's answer is spot-on as to the first part of your question. I'll try to tackle the rest.

Assign is for simple, non-object types such as int, double, or struct. It generates a setter that does a plain old assignment, as in "foo = newFoo". Copy & retain will, as their names imply, either make a copy of the new value ("foo = [newFoo copy]") or retain it ("foo = [newFoo retain]"). In both cases, the setter will release the old value as appropriate.

So the question is, when to copy and when to retain. The answer is... it depends. How does your class use the new value? Will your class break if some other code modifies the incoming object? Say, for example, you have an NSString* property imaginatively named "theString." Other code can assign an NSMutableString instance to theString - that's legal, because it's an NSString subclass. But that other code might also keep its own reference to the mutable string object, and change its value - is your code prepared to deal with that possibility? If not, it should make its own copy, which the other code can't change.

On the other hand, if your own code makes no assumptions about whether theString might have been changed, and works just as well whether or not it was, then you'd save memory by retaining the incoming object instead of unnecessarily making a copy of it.

Basically, the rule, which is unfortunately not so simple sometimes, is to think carefully about whether your own code needs its own private copy, or can correctly deal with a shared object whose value might be changed by other code.

Comment: There are times when you need to use assign on object types though. It's not only for non-object types.

Comment: True - retain cycles, delegates, and connected IBOutlets, to name a few. I was trying to keep it simple, but may have simplified a bit *too* much.

Comment: I've always retained IBOutlets... is there a reason they should be assigned? Are they retained by anything other than your own controller class?

Comment: I was thinking of emulating the old behavior, where an IBOutlet ivar would, if there were no setter method, simply be assigned. Old dogs *can* learn new tricks, but sometimes we have trouble forgetting the old ones...

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can release gc after it is added to the gastroCategoryList is that when an object is added to an array, the array retains that object. So, even though you release your gc, it will still be around; retained by the gastroCategoryList.

When you are returning a newly created object from a method, you need to call `autorelease.` This will cause the object to be released only after the runtime leaves the scope of the calling method, thereby giving the calling method a chance to do something with the returned value.

Note that if your method starts with the word copy or new, then you should *not* autorelease your object; you should leave it for the calling method to release.

As for copy vs retain vs assign... as a general rule, copy objects that have a mutable version, such as NSArray, NSSet, NSDictionary, and NSString. This will ensure that the object you have a pointer to is not mutable when you don't want it to be.

Otherwise, use retain whenever you want your class to be ensured that an object is still in memory. This will apply to almost every object except for objects that are considered parents of your object, in which case you would use assign. (See the section on retain cycles [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html)).

Also note that you have to use assign for non-object types such as int.

Read through the Memory [Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1) a bit; it's quite helpful.